# Upload image with twitter lite

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm using [twitter-lite library](https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite) and I want to twit an image with text.
I'm able to twit only text, but My goal is twit with text and image.

At the moment I'm trying to use a static image like:

```
const fs = require("fs")
    const imageData = fs.readFileSync("./public/images/watermark_update_idea.png")
    const mediaUploadResponse = await client.post('statuses/upload', {
        media:imageData,
    }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
    });
```

But I get that error:

```
    {
  _headers: Headers {
    [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      'cache-control': [Array],
      connection: [Array],
      'content-encoding': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      date: [Array],
      server: [Array],
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      'strict-transport-security': [Array],
      'x-connection-hash': [Array],
      'x-response-time': [Array],
      'x-tsa-request-body-time': [Array]
    }
  },
  errors: [ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ]
}
```

My main goal is to twit with buffer, But I get the same error.
I tried to replicate this [test](https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite/blob/99811f8edea3fa4702f0a3c6d44088bf7367f2a8/test/twitter.test.js#L223) but without lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially two issues here:

1. Use different subdomains for uploading an image and for posting a tweet:

```
const Twitter = require("twitter-lite");
const client = Twitter({/* auth data */});
const upload = Twitter({/* auth data */, subdomain: "upload"});
```

2. You have to convert your image content to a base64 string:

```
const imageData = fs.readFileSync("./public/images/watermark_update_idea.png");

const { media_id_string } = await upload.post('media/upload', {
  media: imageData.toString("base64")
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution. I don't have error, but it doesn't post on twitter